# Check If MenuItem is In ActionBar Overflow

Tags: android, overflow, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

Question: Is there a way to check in code if a MenuItem (or which MenuItems) are in the overflow menu of the ActionBar?
I'm using ActionBarSherlock

The reason I need this is because I have a bunch of icons that will show up in the ActionBar if there is room. I have a holo dark theme so the icons are made to fit that.

My problem comes when the menu items are put into the overflow menu. On Pre-Honeycomb devices this means they will show when the user presses the menu button. This menu is the exact opposite background as my ActionBar and I want to have a different set of icons to fit that.

Comment: icons don't show in the overflow menu items.

Comment: I know they don't. that isn't what i'm asking. I pointed out that i'm interested in pre honeycomb devices (menu icons do show).

Comment: It would also be helpful if we found a way that we could disable icons on the MenuItems which are in the overflow menu so that just the text would appear in legacy menus.

Comment: You should have a look at [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html), it will be easier…

Comment: I've seen this site many times. can you be specific as to where I should be looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have found a solution to this problem: In the Design Guide ([here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#elements)), there is a table that shows how many action bar items are shown depending on the width in dip.

Based on that table I have written the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);

    // Get width in dp
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    float logicalDensity = metrics.density;
    int dp = (int) (display.getWidth() / logicalDensity + 0.5);

    if (dp < 360) { // only two icons
        search.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_search);  // Show menu icon for pre-3.0 menu
    } else {
        search.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search); // Show action bar icon for action bar
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the `Toolbar` then you can create a simple extension in `Kotlin` or static function in `Java` to find if the toolbar menu item is visible on Toolbar or hidden into the overflow option menu.

Here is a sample function and it's use:

```
fun Toolbar.isMenuItemOverflowing(@IdRes id: Int): Boolean {
    return this.findViewById<View>(id) == null
}
```

Using the function with toolbar instance:-

```
toolbar.isMenuItemOverflowing(R.id.action_search)
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer to a similar question that will solve your problem, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18884872/1299562

Basically you can use onPrepareOptionsMenu to remove the non-action item icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection. Put the following code in a class and then invoke `Foo.isInOverflow(yourMenuItem);`

```
protected static final String SUPPORTCLASS = "android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl";

protected static final String NATIVECLASS = "com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl";

protected static Method sSupportIsActionButton;

protected static Method sNativeIsActionButton;

static {
    try {
        Class<?> MenuItemImpl = Class.forName(NATIVECLASS);
        sNativeIsActionButton = MenuItemImpl.getDeclaredMethod("isActionButton");
        sNativeIsActionButton.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    try {
        Class<?> MenuItemImpl = Class.forName(SUPPORTCLASS);
        sSupportIsActionButton = MenuItemImpl.getDeclaredMethod("isActionButton");
        sSupportIsActionButton.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Check if an item is showing (not in the overflow menu).
 * 
 * @param item
 *            the MenuItem.
 * @return {@code true} if the MenuItem is visible on the ActionBar.
 */
public static boolean isActionButton(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getClass().getName()) {
    case SUPPORTCLASS:
        try {
            return (boolean) sSupportIsActionButton.invoke(item, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // fall through
        }
    case NATIVECLASS:
        try {
            return (boolean) sNativeIsActionButton.invoke(item, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // fall through
        }
    default:
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Check if an item is in the overflow menu.
 * 
 * @param item
 *            the MenuItem
 * @return {@code true} if the MenuItem is in the overflow menu.
 * @see #isActionButton(MenuItem)
 */
public static boolean isInOverflow(MenuItem item) {
    return !isActionButton(item);
}
```

Note: you need to add the following line to your proguard configuration file so reflection works in production builds:

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }
```

Comment: Changed this to work with `android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl` but then I get a `NoSuchMethodException` on API 10 (even though I'm building with appcompat version 22 which has that method). And when running on API 22, it works but gives the wrong result (all Action/Toolbar icons are said to be in overflow, even though only some of them are...).

Comment: @Matthias, I updated the code. Please let me know if you still have issues or find something wrong.